# Cascading encryption with blocks or output

Tags: cryptanalysis, provable-security

For educational purposes, I'm trying to build a cascading encryption implementation with AES, Twofish, Blowfish, Salsa20, and ChaCha20. First of all, please don't judge my paranoia or choices, this is just for learning. I don't remember exactly where, but I think that A(B(C(plaintext))), where A, B, and C are ciphers, is bad, because you're putting one cipher in front of another and creating a larger attack surface. I remember hearing that it is better to encrypt each block with A, B, C in CTR mode and then combine: A(B(C(block1)))+A(B(C(block2)))....

Is this true? What is the most optimal way to implement cascading encryption? Thanks.

**Edit: Can anyone find a JS implementation of Serpent? I can't find an implementation anywhere.**

**Example:**

I want to encrypt "Hello world, why am I writing this".

**Method 1 (A(B(C(plaintext)))):**

Ciphertext =

```
Twofish(Serpent(AES("Hello world, why am I writing this")))
```

**Method 2 (A(B(C(block1)))+A(B(C(block2)))...., suppose block size is 8):**

Ciphertext =

```
 Twofish(Serpent(AES("Hello wor")))
+Twofish(Serpent(AES("ld, why ")))
+Twofish(Serpent(AES("am I wri")))
+Twofish(Serpent(AES("ting thi")))
+Twofish(Serpent(AES("s0000000")))
```

Which would be more secure, if there is a difference?

Comment: For the cascade see [How strong can multiple encryption be?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27813/18298). There is a research result on this. The second is not clear, what do you mean by $+$ and $block(i)$, what does prevents the first one to use $block(i)$

Comment: I've added an example to help people understand.

Comment: So $+$ means just concatenation. Do you know about the block size limit of the ciphers and therefore we need [block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)? You seem not aware of this.